# Selecting from one table and insert it in another table using select tag form with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my site. blog_cat, and blog_post_seo I want to select from blog_cat a column (catTile) and insert it data into blog_post_seo table column (catTitle),

this what i try

```
<select name="catTitle">    
<?php
$catsql = "SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle";

$catres = mysql_query($catsql);
while($catrow= mysql_fetch_assoc($catres)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $catrow['catID']. "'>" . $catrow['catTitle'] . "</option>";
}
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
insert into blog_post_seo (field1, field2, field3, ...) values('value1',(select catTitle from blog_cats where id=xx), 'value3', ...)
```

?

Putting this in a for loop, you could populate field1, and field3 and others using either php, or other subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert directly from a select like this:

```
INSERT INTO blog_post_seo (catTitle)
SELECT catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle
```

This is of course assuming your column is named `catTitle` in both tables.